What grass is this? Sydney, Australia
Patches of this grass started growing very quickly a few weeks back after a threw some fertiliser on the lawn. What type of grass is it? We're in Sydney, Australia.




try using Google lens to identify the grass

not sure, but looks like tall fescue grass

I sent the photos to my gardener and he said it's wintergrass.
